# Algorithm : Find the least wastage in cutting the Trees?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given n Trees with their heights in an array.
and you are given a value k units , that much wood you need to collect.
You can have an axe of any height you want but you can use only 1 axe when you choose.

tell the most optimum height of axe you should use and which trees you will cut so that you get the minimum wastage.

if you cut a tree of height H with an axe of height X.
If H>X you get H-X wood
else 0 wood

I tries this problem but i am not able to think apart from brute-force which is pretty bad complexity.

UPDATE to queries below
:-
If the axe height is 0 it is not ncessary that there will be 0 wastage
say the tree heights are 2,4 and k is 5. I hope this makes the query clear.

In the above case the height of axe is 0 and i need to cut 2 trees to obtain 5 units of wood.
and the wastage will be 1 units which we have to minimise and it is minimum here

There is no need of other parameters like force or anything else

Comment: Cannot understand your question. if the height of axe is 0, you don't waste any wood, right? Can you give some examples?

Comment: There is no (physical) direct relationship between the height of the axe and the height of the trees: you cannot determine how many trees you can cut, the effort required, etc. without bringing other variables into account (e.g., force applied to the axe, point where this force is applied, point of contact with the tree, resistance of the tree in the cutting point, etc.). You have to introduce lots of physical variables for proper calculations or lots of restrictions for simplistic calculations; but much more information is required anyway.

Comment: From the explanation about the wood quantity, I think the "height of axe" is the height above ground at which the cut will be made.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the explanations above are pretty confusing; but even in case that you are right this does not tell anything either. If you want to do it extremely simple, logically, the easiest to be cut would be the shortest trees. If you want to increase a (tiny) level of complexity and bring width into the picture, it would be impossible to tell just with this information. Either way the exact point where the force is applied is secondary as far as it only becomes relevant while considering further issues (proper definition of tree and force).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan there might be another simplistic interpretation: calculating the moment (on the top) by assuming constant width. In that case you would also have to bring the force being applied in each tree into consideration.

Comment: @all i have added comments to make your query clear.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes you said it right

Comment: Does the height have to be an integral value? In the 2/4 case, you could cut at height 0.5, which would give you 1.5 + 3.5 = 5, exactly what you need. If it doesn't have to be integral, this problem is trivial.

Comment: I think the axe (set to whatever height above ground you choose) will be used to cut *all* trees of at least that height.  At least, this (a) makes sense, and (b) always allows a 0-waste solution.

Comment: Does the axe height have to be nonnegative? If not, you can always cut the first tree with an axe of height k - H1.

Comment: Axe height has to be non-negative , can be non integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT 12/9/2013: Fixed formula in last sentence!]**

It is always possible to choose an axe height such that chopping *all* trees above this height will result in zero waste.

To see this, just sort the trees in descending order of height, and consider moving the axe height gradually down from the top of the tallest tree.  Suppose the tallest tree has height h.  Notice that the function

```
f(x) = total amount of wood cut by using an axe of height h - x to
       chop all trees of at least this height
```

starts at 0 when x = 0, and is an increasing piecewise linear function of x, with no discontinuities.  Every time x increases past the point when one or more trees just start to become choppable, the rate of change of f(x) increases, but this doesn't cause problems.  So for any desired level of wood y, just (conceptually) intersect a horizontal line of height y with the graph f(x), and drop a vertical line from this point down to the x axis to find its value.  (How to actually do this in a program I leave as an exercise, but here's a hint: consider trees in decreasing height order to find the pair of adjacent x values x1, x2 such that chopping at h - x1 produces too little wood, and h - x2 produces too much.)

Comment: can you simplify your language a bit. You said strat when x = 0 , and increase x when one or more trees become choppable , but when x = 0 , the entire tree is choppable. I am not sure how to draw the graph. For every value of x there will be n points in vertical line in graph. can we take an example and plot a graph let say height of trees are 7,5,4,3. the desired value can be say 5. Also can be 17. giving 17 here we will have to cut entire forest.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Peter's comments suggest that the axe height needs to be integral. (I'm not the down voter BTW.)

Comment: @ErikP.: I don't actually see anything in Peter's comment here (or on the question itself) to suggest that -- what do you see?

Comment: @Peter For trees 7,5,4,3 the key axe heights and wood amounts are (7,0), (5,2), (4,4), (3, 7), (0,19). If the target is 5, we should cut between 3 and 4. Cutting at 4 gets 4 units, so we need one more unit. We get 3 units of wood per unit of axe height, so we should lower the axe from 4 by 1/3 units, and cut at 3.6666666... for zero wastage.

Comment: @j_random_hacker just the examples that Peter gives: the only reason that we'd have to cut the entire forest of 7,5,4,3 if the desired quantity is 17 that I could think of is if the height needs to be an integer. Same for the 2,4 forest with k=5. That and the fact that it becomes a nontrivial problem in that case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), an NP-complete problem, is reducible to the problem of selecting the best set of trees for a given axe height. That portion of your problem is NP-hard, and the best known algorithms have exponential complexity.

Comment: The fact that we get to choose which trees get cut is actually a red herring ;-) It's always possible to find an axe height such that chopping all trees above that height gives 0 waste -- see my answer.

Comment: But the fact that we can choose the axe height invalidates that reduction, doesn't it? If we have an oracle that solves the tree cutting problem for us, we can't restrict it to a particular axe height, so I don't see how we can use it to solve a particular instance of subset sum.

Comment: @ErikP.  Correct. It only means that we cannot, in general, work by evaluating the cost of arbitrary axe positions. I have already upvoted j_random_hacker's answer, and I'm disappointed to see it at net zero votes, and not yet accepted.

Answer (score 0):

seems like eko question of spoj...

1)sort the height of the trees.
2)subtract the a[i](greater height)-a[j](lesser height tree) multipled by the total tree considered till yet to be cut...

for more detail how to work look through the code of

```
    #define gu getchar();
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
    inline int scan()
    {
        int n=0;
        char ch=gu;
        while(ch<48){ch=gu;}
        while(ch>47){n=(n<<3)+(n<<1)+ch-'0';ch=gu;}
        return n;
    }
bool dec(ll i,ll j)
{
    return (i>j);
}
ll a[1000000]={0};
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    ll l,m;
    scanf("%d %lld",&n,&m);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%lld",a+i);
    sort(a,a+n,greater<ll>());
    //for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      //  printf("%lld ",a[i]);
    ll k=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        //printf("*%lld ",m);
        if(a[i]==k)
            continue;
        if((m-((i)*(k-a[i])))<=0)
        {
            if((m-((i)*(k-a[i])))==0)
            {printf("%d\n",a[i]);break;}
            else
            {
                ll z=(ll)(m/(i+1));
                m=m-z*(i);
                if(m==0)
                {printf("%lld\n",k-z);break;}
                if(m-(i+1)<0)
                {printf("%lld\n",k-z-1);break;}
            }
            printf("%lld ",m);
        }
        m=m-((i)*(k-a[i]));
        k=a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```